# Formatting for loops in Octave correctly

Tags: formatting, octave

It probably has no practical consequences, but it makes me think I'm doing something wrong...

When creating a `for` loop in Octave, the bracketing on the left gray bar of the editor (along the line numbers) doesn't stay with the `end` closing line. It rather seems tethered to the first line *after* the loop, and keeps on widening with every return if the cursor is at the beginning of the line following the loop.

Introducing tab spaces in front of `end` doesn't seem to do the trick in terms of "linking" the bracket to the `end` line.

Here is an example:

[image]

Serendipitously, I found a "way" to keep the bracket end align with the `end` command: just insert a backslash:

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting the indentation of the `end` to actually match the `for`?

Comment: @Suever That is exactly what I don't know how to do.

Comment: Ummm....you delete the spaces before the `end`. You have two spaces on the line that precede the `end`

Comment: @Suever I see your point (about the 2 spaces). I tried now getting rid of them, and aligning the bracket with `end`, but if I tried to insert an empty, separating space between `end` and `subplot` the bracket would follow down the page, away from `end`.

Comment: Ok then it just must be how the editor is. A code folding region must encompass all whitespace following a block which actually makes sense. There is nothing actually wrong with your `for` loop.

Comment: @Suever It works... but I can't introduce any spaces between the bracket and the code the follows. The example on the picture is actually from an online youtube presentation, and I can see how the bracket stays with `end` on the video. It might have to do with Matlab v. Octave, but I doubt it.

Comment: If you think it's a bug, I would [file it](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave&func=additem) with Octave

Comment: I can't see the described behaviour with GNU Octave 4.2.0 on Debain jessie. It's always worth to mention which version, build and OS you are using....

Comment: @Andy GNU Octave, version 4.2.1